# How can I find the Fourier Transform of a function given its time-plot using the Fourier Transform of another function?

Tags: graphing-functions, inverse, fourier-transform

So I have $$X(Ω) = -j\frac{2π}{ω}δ(ω)$$

And I need to find the Fourier Transform of

[image]

and I need to find the Fourier transform of a square pulse $g(t) = 1 \text{ for } |t|<1.$

But I don't know where to start. I know how to get the Fourier Transform of the square pulse normally but no idea how to do it while using another Fourier Transform.

Comment: You can explore the fact that the square pulse is the derivative of the function you have its Fourier transform plus one.

Comment: You mean I have to take the derivative of Χ(Ω) + 1?

Comment: No. The derivative of the inverse transform of $X$ plus one is the pulse. $F^{-1}(X)$ is a straight line. But not sure about the utility of that.

Comment: It is indeed a straight line, that was my original function but I didn't mention it because I didn't think it was needed.